# How to make an intersection function with linked lists?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Here is the linked lists code, so how to make two different lists and display the intersection between them?
 For example there is two linked lists called L1 and L2, so how to implement a function that displays the intersection of these two lists, like L1 has 1,2,3,4,5 and L2 has 11,3,4
so the result would be 3,4.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Node.h"

class DoublyLinkedList{
private:
    Node* head; 
    Node* tail;
    Node* list; 
    int elementCount;

public:
    DoublyLinkedList(){

        head = tail = list = NULL;
        elementCount = 0;
    }

    void insertAtFront(int item){
        elementCount++;
        Node* newNode;
        newNode = new Node;
        newNode->data = item;
        list = head;

        if(list == NULL) { 
            head = newNode;
            tail = head;
            return;
        }

        newNode->next = head;
        head->prev = newNode;
        head = newNode;


        head->prev = tail;
        tail->next = head;
    }

    void insertAtEnd(int item){
        elementCount++;
        Node* newNode;
        newNode = new Node;
        newNode->data = item;
        list = head;

        if(list == NULL){ 
            head = newNode;
            tail = head;
            return;
        }

        tail->next = newNode;
        newNode->prev = tail;
        tail = newNode;


        head->prev = tail; 
        tail->next = head;
    }


    bool insertAtIndex(int item, int index){
        if(index > elementCount){
            cout << "Invalid index" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else if(index == 0){
            insertAtFront(item);
        }
        else if(index == elementCount){
            insertAtEnd(item);
        } 
        else {
            Node* newNode = new Node;
            newNode->data = item;

            list = getNodeAt(index - 1);

            newNode->next = list->next; 
            list->next->prev = newNode;
            list->next = newNode;
            newNode->prev = list;
            elementCount++;
        }
        return true;
    }

};
```

Comment: Two `for` loops ought to do the trick.

Comment: You may look at `std::set_intersection` (but it requires iterator, and sorted lists).

Comment: Use merge sort to sort the individual lists. Then do a standard merge to find the items that are common to both lists.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a learning assignment, here is a general description of the approach:

- Define a function `bool contains(int value) const` that takes an `int value` and returns `true` when the list contains the specified value; this function will have a loop in it.
- Define a function `DoublyLinkedList intersectWith(DoublyLinkedList& other) const` that produces the intersection by following the algorithm below:
- Create a new `DoublyLinkedList result`
- For each item of this list, call `other.contains(node.data)`
- If the function returned `true`, check that `result.contains(node.data)` returns `false` to eliminate duplicates
- If `other.contains(node.data) && !result.contains(node.data)`, add `node.data` to `result`
- Continue to the next node until this list is exhausted
- Return the `result` list.

Comment: @Jarod42 You are right, I needed to expand the explanation to cover duplicates. Thanks!